# call a static method within originating class

Tags: php

I'm looking for a way to replace `__NAMESPACE__` in the following code:

```
namespace classes\utility;
class Cleanse
{
    public static function escape($values)
    {
        return is_array($values) ?
                    array_map(__NAMESPACE__.'\Cleanse::escape', $values) :
                    htmlentities($values, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    }
}
```

From doing some reading, I tried this:

```
public static function escape($values)
{
    return is_array($values) ?
                array_map([static::class, 'escape'], $values) :
                htmlentities($values, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}
```

but got this error:

***Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$'***
and it referred to the `array_map` line of code.

I'm looking for a solution that's compatible with PHP version 5.4.4 and above, and something that is not going to be deprecated any time soon.

EDIT: I was unable to find the answer in the proposed duplicate post because it is so long.  Therefore, I do not agree that this is a duplicate posting.

Comment: Both worked for me, what PHP version are you using?

Comment: Change was 5.5? "Class name resolution via ::class" fwiw... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them

Comment: I'm using version 5.4.4.

Comment: You might have to use [get_called_class()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-called-class.php) instead of `static::class`

Comment: Try to upgrade also... PHP 5.4 was EOL in 2015?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you've said you're using PHP 5.4, you will need to use http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-called-class.php

Replace

```
static::class
```

With

```
get_called_class()
```

Because the *static::class* syntax was added in version 5.5.0

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.changelog.php

> 5.5.0     Added: The ::class magic constant.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the `__METHOD__` magic constant as this is a recurisve call.

```
namespace classes\utility;

class Cleanse
{
    public static function escape($values)
    {

        //array_map(__CLASS__.'::escape', $values) :
        //array_map(__CLASS__.'::'.__FUNCTION__, $values) :
        //etc... all work
        return is_array($values) ?
                    array_map(__METHOD__, $values) :
                    htmlentities($values, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    }
}

$C = new Cleanse();
print_r( $C->escape(["foo"]) );
```

Output

```
['foo']
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2938539da95125a6f1c087b04a0dc2774bc8d3ba) *-note- you can change PHP versions in the sandbox, for example changing it to 5.4*

If you are worried about overwriting and late static binding then you have to use `get_called_class` no matter what.  But that shouldn't be an issue with a recursive call one would think, as if you overwrite it, then it is still the method and it doesn't access any internal data to the class.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
class MyClass {
    const CONST_VALUE = 'A constant value';
}

$classname = 'MyClass';
echo $classname::CONST_VALUE; // As of PHP 5.3.0

echo MyClass::CONST_VALUE;
?>
```

Three special keywords self, parent and static are used to access properties or methods from inside the class definition.

**Example #2 :: from inside the class definition**

```
<?php
class OtherClass extends MyClass
{
    public static $my_static = 'static var';

    public static function doubleColon() {
        echo parent::CONST_VALUE . "\n";
        echo self::$my_static . "\n";
    }
}

$classname = 'OtherClass';
$classname::doubleColon(); // As of PHP 5.3.0

OtherClass::doubleColon();
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php

Comment: Can you give an example of accessing a static method from within the class where it's defined?  That is what I'm having trouble with.

Comment: what happen when yout try like this self::callyourMethod();

Comment: When I tried `self::escape()` it gave 3 warnings and 2 notices.